# 16.04 hangs with AMD drivers so do I have to install 15.10 to get fglrx back?

Tags: 16.04, radeon, amd-graphics

SO I read the warning

"If you use the AMD Catalyst (fglrx) driver on Ubuntu you may wish to avoid upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS next month."

and figured that I wouldn't get hit with it so like a moron I installed 16.04!!

BUT I run Kodi streaming media to watch tv and it keeps locking up as I no longer have the old fglrx/catalyst driver which worked fine.

It's too expensive to replace my card SO is the only option to reinstall and old version of Ubuntu OR is there a new driver out there I can install?? if so where is the web site please?

My card XFX AMD Radeon HD 5450 2GB DDR3 VGA/DVI/HDMI PCI-Express Video Card ON-XFX1-DLX2

the article with the explanation of the issue

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, there is no AMD proprietary driver for 16.04. There is a beta driver, called AMD GPU-PRO, but it's a beta (yes it's redundant, I'm tired :P) and it's limited to very few cards.

For now, and probably forever, judging from the way AMD has treated its cards in the past, you are stuck with the open source driver unless you do one of a few things.

For one, you can buy a new card. I know you said you can't afford one, but maybe it's time to save up for a cheap NVIDIA. NVIDIA cards tend to be unstable on Ubuntu, but at least they get support for more than two years.

Another option is to downgrade. Back up `/home/` so you have all your user data and install Ubuntu 14.04. 15.10 is newer, but it's about to reach its end of life, as it isn't an LTS release.

And of course, you could always just pray and wait for a proprietary AMD driver that works on 16.04. Who knows? Maybe some developer will get `fglrx` running on Xorg 1.18 (v1.18 is what broke `fglrx` compatibility. Xorg is the display server.).

Honestly, I would just save up for an NVIDIA card. I have an Ubuntu box set up with AMD graphics on 16.04 and I'm considering getting a cheap, 1GB VRAM NVIDIA card to replace the AMD.

Comment: a gentleman and a scholar thank you @zacharee1 I'm going to reload 15.nn ( all I do is run kodi so I am fine with end of life, thanks for the heads up thought. I will also take your advice to backup /home/  A new 1/2 height card for my media machine costs more than I paid for it :-)  thanks again you are GREAT

Comment: No problem :). Just remember, we don't support EOL releases on AU, and any questions about EOL releases are closed. [unix.se] still supports EOL releases if you do need further help.

Comment: again thanks I did not know Au didn't support EOL so I suppose I will have to read the rules :-)  I'm kinda stuck as my machine needs a half height card and I can't find a cheap one. Ho hum thanks again

Comment: @theakson I can take a look.

Comment: @theakson is $60 OK?

Comment: bit too rich for my blood :-) I was hoping for $40 how about this one https://www.amazon.com/MSI-GeForce-PCI-Express-N610GT-MD1GD3-LP/dp/B008D1JKDQ/ref=sr_1_sc_1?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1467527496&sr=1-1-spell&keywords=nvidia+low+profice+pci

Comment: @theakson MSI is good. 1GB VRAM is enough for most things. High rating.  However, I don't think the frame is low-profile even though the card could be

Comment: thanks @Zacharee1 I'll fix it up when I get it. I am taking your advice and buying a new card so I can keep running 16.04 you have been a great help thanks

Comment: @theakson just be careful with that frame. You can remove the VGA component easily, but bending the frame is near impossible (I know from experience). You should buy a low profile frame and install that on the card.

Comment: will do and thanks for all your help. Going to sleep now happy 4th

Comment: [This](http://www.ebay.com/itm/PCI-E-Video-Card-Half-Height-DVI-HDMI-New-Low-Profile-bracket-for-ATI-or-Nvidia-/191818395766?hash=item2ca9447076:g:1eMAAOSwSdZWc-kQ) will provide space for the DVI and HDMI ports. [Here's a separate VGA](http://www.ebay.com/itm/ATI-Nvidia-Video-Card-Low-Profile-Bracket-VGA-For-Graphic-Card-/251879089188?hash=item3aa529e424:g:FywAAOSweW5VBD82) for if you have two available slots. You too :)